# C# cmd - Invalid expression term, )expected Exiftool

Tags: c#, cmd, exif, exiftool

I'm Re-Creating the "command prompt" into a Windows Form. The application is not working properly; and i can't find error.

```
 exiftool photo_file.jpg |find "Shutter Count"
```

That's command working properly in command prompt.
Any idea what i am missing here?

```
   private void btncheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String StrCmdText;
        var process = Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/c exiftool " + txtBrowse.Text + " |find "Shutter Count"");
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
```

Comment: You need to escape your quote marks: `" |find \"Shutter Count\""`

Comment: You don't need to pipe the output of Exiftool to filter the results.  You can use `exiftool -ShutterCount ` to get just the ShutterCount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use string literal `\"` and change the code to

```
var process = Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/c exiftool " + txtBrowse.Text + " |find \"Shutter Count\"");
```

or

```
var process = Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/c exiftool " + txtBrowse.Text + " |find ""Shutter Count""");
```

Answer (score 1):

try to start the process with arguments like this...

```
var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c arguments here";
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.Start();
```